# Is there a way to simplify this bit of code without having to call the same functions over and over again?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am playing around with Project Euler and I have a file full of primes.

I have a function that looks through those primes and pulls out the prime factors. The expression I am using is as follows

```
def prime_factors(n, fastfactor=True):
    if fastfactor:
        with open(primefile, 'r') as primelist:
            primes = [int(x.strip()) for x in primelist if int(x.strip()) <= n and n % int(x.strip()) == 0]
    return primes
```

The code works fine, however I wanted to simplify the list expression to something like this:

```
[x for int(x.strip()) in primelist if x <= n and n % x == 0]
```

However I cannot figure anything out to simplify and make clearer this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop obviously, storing the result of `int(x.strip())`:

A one-line way is a nested list comprehension (with a generator inside of the comprehension):

```
[x for x in (int(x_raw.strip()) for x_raw in primelist) if x <= n and n % x == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I opted to just break it into several lines to avoid the nested for loops, I appreciate your help and I did try the answer, but I would be worried about the speed for larger files.